# format of returned result for .objects.filter(name__containe=data) without quotes sign

Tags: django, database, filter, single-quotes, outputformat

I have written a code by django in which a user can search for a word in a table of database. My problem here is when I print the returned results, they contain quotations. How can I omit them?

```
def My_data_filed(request):
    form = data_filed_Form(request.POST or None)
    data = None
    download_form = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            data_g = form.cleaned_data.get('g')
            data = list(data_filed.objects.filter(g__contains=data_g).values())
            print(data_filed.objects.all().values())
            download_form = data_filed_DownloadForm(initial={
                'g': data_g,
            })

    return render(request, 'search_report.html',
                  {
                      'form': form,
                      'data': data,
                      'download_form': download_form
                  })
```

The output of this code is like:

```
 'Creator': 'Davide'
```

But I just want to have:

```
Davide
```

Whats wrong in my effort?

---

My code for writing the fetched result into a csv file: (Since from the comments I understood this part is related too)

```
def resultDownload(request):
    try:
        assert request.method == 'POST'
        form = data_DownloadForm(request.POST)
        assert form.is_valid()
        data_g = form.cleaned_data.get('g')
        data = list(data_filed.objects.filter(data__contains=g).values_list())
    except AssertionError:
        error = 'Your request has some problems.'
        data = error

    attachment = 'SearchedReport.csv'
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="{}"'.format(attachment)
    response.write(data)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run a queryset like data_filed.objects.filter(g__contains=data_g).values() it always returns a dictionary kind of output with keys and values. And when you passed that result to your template file using:

```
return render(request, 'search_report.html',
                  {
                      'form': form,
                      'data': data,
                      'download_form': download_form
                  })
```

It is still in that format. If you want to output only the value, you need to output it as such

```
{{ data.Creator }}
```

That will give you the output "Davide" without the quotes

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me where I should write this `{{ data.Creator }} `?

Comment: If its place is in the templates, I must mention that I don't return the search result to the templates. I am saving them in a csv file and return that file. Is this work in this situation too?

Comment: If I change `.values()` to `.values_list` I suppose I will have no longer a dictionary. So I won't have `'Creator': 'Davide'`, instead I will have `'Davide'`. But the quotes are still there and I dont receive `Davide` without quoutes:((

Comment: {{ data.Creator }} should be written in the template file 'search_report.html'. But since you are writing to a CSV file. That will not work for you. The template tags are only meant to be displayed on a Django templates file.

Comment: Can I see source code of how you are writing this search result to a CSV file?

Comment: @ Psalms Kalu: Yes I edited my question and added this part of code too.